# How to make SwiftUI Text multilineTextAlignment start from Top and Center

Tags: gridview, swiftui, android-gravity, lazyvgrid, lazyhgrid

[image]

How can I make the image and text alignment same as 3 other in SwiftUI LazyVGrid as I expected in image below?

I think the problem is how to make the text start from top if the text is multiline. In Android I can use gravity="top|center" but in SwiftUI I use .multilineTextAlignment(.center) but the result not as I expected.

[image]

Here what I just try in my code:

```
      LazyVGrid(columns: gridItemLayout, spacing: 0) {
          ForEach((0...7), id: \.self) { i in
               VStack {
                    RemoteImageView(url: vm.listService[i].image_uri)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    Text(vm.listService[i].name)
                        .font(.body)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
               }
         }
      }
      .padding(.horizontal, 25.0)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the `Text`'s frame, you need to:

1. set `maxHeight` to `.infinity`, so it can expand vertically too
2. set `alignment` to `.top`, so it's aligned to the top

```
let names = ["Hi", "Hello world", "Long long text"]

let gridItemLayout = [
   GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 80))
]

var body: some View {
    
    LazyVGrid(columns: gridItemLayout, spacing: 0) {
        ForEach((0...7), id: \.self) { i in
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "folder")
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .background(Color.green)
                Text(names.randomElement() ?? "")
                .font(.body)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                
                /// here!
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
            }
        }
    }
    .padding(.horizontal, 25.0)
}
```

Result:

[image: Grid of elements composed of an Image on top of a Text. The Image's y position is always the same, while the Text expands down when it has multiple lines.]